# where is the best place to store big data schema

Tags: sql, nosql, graph-databases

The question name may seem irrelevant, but I couldn't find a name best fit for my intent.

I am working on an e-commerce project and using a relational database for storage. But I have a little issue with the performance my product domain queries. The thing we want to accomplish is a little bit complex, so the way we designed the database schema is a little bit complex. We have over 40 tables for product domain and we are having some performance problems while querying the db to make our product pages work. To view some simple information about a product we need to query at least 5-7 table and this causes a huge penalty for website since we have hundreds of thousands of requests per day.

By the way our data is not big. The problem is, we have many tables containing little data and we have to join many of them at a time.

Is there a better way or place to store such data? I have looked at nosql dbs, but as I understand they might not be the best fit for my solution. Can a graph db like neo4j be helpful in my case?

Thanks for any help...

Comment: With no information about what you are actually storing (other than it is some kind of product) it is impossible to suggest if there is a better way to store the data. Querying 5-7 tables per request is not likely to be an issue if those tables are properly indexed, but again this is a guess because I have no idea what is in those tables.

Comment: Actually I didn't want to give specific table names or relations about schema to keep my point clear. Joins from 5-7 tables are the minor ones. I have to query nearly 15 tables to list products in our productlist page. Mainly, I have 2 tables and other tables are all related to one of these tables. What I am looking for is a fast way to query this relation tree in a tolerable time. That's why I am wandering if this can be done faster than a relational database like Ms Sql Server.

Comment: This question is really hard to answer as it currently stands. You might have either a design problem or a more simple not indexed properly problem. There are also tricks that can be played depending on what and how the data is used. You might like to pick the most important query and ask a question about how to speed it up. Those sorts of questions seem to be popular and might help.  If you do this, please put the query, execution plan, table schema and index details in your question.